# System.IO.Ports leer puerto com3 tipo de dato recibido Wiegand 26, c# leer

Tags: c#

Hola podrian apoyarme con este tema
estoy leyendo por medio de una terminal una tarjeta de proximidad, que me dice su documentacion que su output de salida es un formato wiegand 26bits

al utilizar el metodo ReadExisting() me regresa un string al que no le entiendo nada. desgraciadamente no les puedo poner la cadena por que me despedirían

buscando informacion en internet me tope con estas reglas. que se suponen son para ese formato wiegand26

El primer Bit, B0, es la Paridad Par de los primeros 12 bits transmitidos (B1:12).
   - Los 8 siguientes, B1:B8 son un Byte, un Entero de 8 bits, al que llaman Facility Code.
   - Los 16 siguientes: B9:B24 son dos Bytes, un Entero de 16 Bits, al que llaman User Code
   - El último bit, B25, es la Paridad Impar de los últimos 12 bits transmitidos (B13:24).

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.serialPort1.Close();
    this.serialPort1.Open();
    this.serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.Mark;
}
```

aqui intento obtener los valores pero no lo logro

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        string texto = this.serialPort1.BytesToRead.ToString();
        string texto2 = this.serialPort1.BytesToWrite.ToString();
        string texto3 = this.serialPort1.DataBits.ToString();
        string texto5 = this.serialPort1.ReadExisting();

        List<byte> tipos = new List<byte>();
        //creo una cadena en donde se guardarán todas las tramas
        foreach (char caracterc in texto5)  //la cadena o trama que creé y he recibido
        {
           // string r = this.ConvertHex(caracterc);
            byte byteCaracter = (byte)caracterc;
            tipos.Add(byteCaracter);
        }

        string result = this.ConvertHex(texto5);

        string pru = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tipos.ToArray());




        textBox1.Text = "";
        this.serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
        this.serialPort1.Close();
        textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { textBox1.Text = texto5; }));
        //textBox1.Text = texto;
    }
```

puse el Parity en parity.mark por que segun lei el primer bit es el parity pero la verdad me falta mucho y no encuentro el norte, espero y puedan ayudarme

De antemano muchas Gracias